# AWS CloudFormation. Calling synchronously Step Function from API Gateway v1

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway, aws-step-functions

I am trying to synchronously execute AWS Step Function via API Gateway. The problem is that with API Gateway V1 I have to use OpenAPI syntax (i.e. swagger) in order to specify `integrationSubtype` parameter, but something just doesn't work. Here is CloudFormation template I am using:

```
{
    "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
    "Parameters": {
        "restApiName": {
            "Type": "String",
            "Default": "stepApi"
        }
    },
    "Resources": {
        "MyStepFunction": {
            "Type": "AWS::StepFunctions::StateMachine",
            "Properties": {
                "StateMachineName": "HelloWorld-StateMachine",
                "StateMachineType": "EXPRESS",
                "DefinitionString": "{\"Comment\": \"A Hello World example of the Amazon States Language using Pass states\", \"StartAt\": \"Hello\", \"States\": {\"Hello\": { \"Type\": \"Pass\", \"Result\": \"Hello\", \"Next\": \"World\" }, \"World\": { \"Type\": \"Pass\", \"Result\": \"World\", \"End\": true } } }",
                "RoleArn": {
                    "Fn::GetAtt": [
                        "StepFunctionRole",
                        "Arn"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        "StepFuncGateway": {
            "Type": "AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi",
            "Properties": {
                "Name": {
                    "Ref": "restApiName"
                },
                "Body": {
                    "openapi": "3.0.1",
                    "info": {
                        "title": "processFormExample",
                        "version": "2020-11-06 15:32:29UTC"
                    },
                    "paths": {
                        "/step": {
                            "post": { 
                                "responses": {
                                    "200": {
                                      "description": "Pet updated.",
                                      "content": {
                                        "application/json": {},
                                        "application/xml": {}
                                      }
                                    },
                                    "405": {
                                        "description": "Method Not Allowed",
                                        "content": {
                                            "application/json": {},
                                            "application/xml": {}
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                "parameters": [
                                ],
                                "x-amazon-apigateway-integration": {
                                    "integrationSubtype": "StepFunctions-StartSyncExecution",
                                    "credentials": {
                                        "Fn::GetAtt": [
                                            "APIGatewayRole", 
                                            "Arn"
                                        ]
                                    },
                                    "RequestTemplates": {
                                        "application/json": {
                                            "Fn::Join": [
                                                "",
                                                [
                                                    "#set( $body = $util.escapeJavaScript($input.json('$')) ) \n\n{\"input\": \"$body\",\"name\": \"$context.requestId\",\"stateMachineArn\":\"",
                                                    {
                                                        "Ref": "MyStepFunction"
                                                    },
                                                    "\"}"
                                                ]
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "httpMethod": "POST",
                                    "payloadFormatVersion": "1.0",
                                    "passthroughBehavior": "NEVER",
                                    "type": "AWS_PROXY",
                                    "connectionType": "INTERNET"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "x-amazon-apigateway-cors": {
                        "allowMethods": [
                            "*"
                        ],
                        "maxAge": 0,
                        "allowCredentials": false,
                        "allowOrigins": [
                            "*"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            },
            "DependsOn": [
                "APIGatewayRole",
                "MyStepFunction"
            ]
        },
        "APIGatewayRole": {
            "Type": "AWS::IAM::Role",
            "Properties": {
                "AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {
                    "Version": "2012-10-17",
                    "Statement": [
                        {
                            "Effect": "Allow",
                            "Principal": {
                                "Service": [
                                    "apigateway.amazonaws.com"
                                ]
                            },
                            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "Path": "/",
                "ManagedPolicyArns": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonAPIGatewayPushToCloudWatchLogs",
                    "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSStepFunctionsFullAccess"
                ]
            }
        },
        "StepFunctionRole": {
            "Type": "AWS::IAM::Role",
            "Properties": {
                "AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {
                    "Version": "2012-10-17",
                    "Statement": [
                        {
                            "Sid": "",
                            "Effect": "Allow",
                            "Principal": {
                                "Service": "states.amazonaws.com"
                            },
                            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "Path": "/",
                "ManagedPolicyArns": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaRole"
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    "Outputs": {
        "HelloWorldApi": {
            "Description": "Sync WF API endpoint",
            "Value": {
                "Fn::Sub": "https://${StepFuncGateway}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/step"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The error I am seeing is following:

> Errors found during import:   Unable to put integration on 'POST' for
> resource at path '/step': Invalid integration URI specified (Service:
> AmazonApiGateway; Status Code: 400; Error Code: BadRequestException;
> Request ID: 0c74acf9-147f-4561-9f4f-e457096c5533; Proxy: null)

I am out of ideas. Please help me to fix it.

**UPDATE:**

I had to add following code into `x-amazon-apigateway-integration` section and change type to `AWS`:

```
"uri": {
    "Fn::Join": [
        "",
        [
            "arn:aws:apigateway:",
            {
                "Ref": "AWS::Region"
            },
            ":states:action/StartSyncExecution"
        ]
    ]
},
```

Another thing I had to fix is `RequestTemplates`, it should start with lower case `r`. After mentioned change the stack was deployed correctly, but now I have throttling problem to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x-amazon-apigateway-integration` is missing the `uri` property.

From the [Amazon Developer Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-swagger-extensions-integration.html), the URI property is defined as:

> The endpoint URI of the backend. For integrations of the aws type,
> this is an ARN value. For the HTTP integration, this is the URL of the
> HTTP endpoint including the https or http scheme.

For example:

```
"x-amazon-apigateway-integration": {
    "type": "AWS_PROXY",
    "httpMethod": "POST",
    "uri": "http://petstore.execute-api.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/petstore/pets",
    "payloadFormatVersion": 1.0,
    "otherPropterties": "go here"
}
```

Amazon has additional information on URI definitions [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/api-reference/resource/integration/). (Copied for convienience)

> For HTTP or HTTP_PROXY integrations, the URI must be a fully formed, encoded HTTP(S) URL according to the RFC-3986 specification, for either standard integration, where connectionType is not VPC_LINK, or private integration, where connectionType is VPC_LINK. For a private HTTP integration, the URI is not used for routing.

> For AWS or AWS_PROXY integrations, the URI is of the form `arn:aws:apigateway:{region}:{subdomain.service|service}:path|action/{service_api}`. Here, `{Region}` is the API Gateway region (e.g., us-east-1); `{service}` is the name of the integrated AWS service (e.g., s3); and `{subdomain}` is a designated subdomain supported by certain AWS service for fast host-name lookup. action can be used for an AWS service action-based API, using an `Action={name}&{p1}={v1}&p2={v2}...` query string. The ensuing `{service_api}` refers to a supported action `{name}` plus any required input parameters. Alternatively, path can be used for an AWS service path-based API. The ensuing `service_api` refers to the path to an AWS service resource, including the region of the integrated AWS service, if applicable. For example, for integration with the S3 API of `GetObject`, the uri can be either `arn:aws:apigateway:us-west-2:s3:action/GetObject&Bucket={bucket}&Key={key}` or `arn:aws:apigateway:us-west-2:s3:path/{bucket}/{key}`

Comment: I tried adding it in the following format: `"Uri": { "Fn::Join": ["", [ "arn:aws:apigateway:", { "Ref": "AWS::Region" }, ":states:action/StartSyncExecution" ] ] },` but it did not work as well. Could you please point me to a resource where I can read about the URI format?

Comment: Added additional info to the answer.